# Query a different density of points based on zoom level in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, clustering

I have a database (using PostGIS) of a few million points that I load onto an interactive map. Obviously the map can't handle this many points, so I currently restrict it by limiting to the points closest to the center of the map. This works great when zoomed in, but shows a tiny cluster of points when zoomed out.

Instead, I'd like to show a sampling of points that represents the visible area.

Here's an example of the functionality I want to copy. As you zoom out, points that are nearby are merged into a single point and as you move in, you can see more detail.

https://www.lds.org/maps/meetinghouses/

How can I accomplish this in a performant way?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like the [pointstacker](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.2.0/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html) in Geoserver. Such things can also be achieved client-side, with clustering, OpenLayers, Leaflet, GoogleM all support clustering, but, of course, it is expensive to send so much data down the wire, only to render somme of it. Postgis supports clustering algorithms, but they are more analytical -- find clusters based on common attributes, k-means, DBscan, etc. I don't know enough about your particular software stack to give a more coherent answer.

Comment: I can shape the software stack to whatever it needs to be. :) With the number of points I'm looking at, I need to do the aggregation server side. I currently use Django, PostGIS, AngularJS, and MapBox. I doubt those details help to know, but there they are.

Comment: Would [random sampling](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/) help you?

Comment: @MickT, interesting, and something I have used in a different context. But, it would be entirely possible to totally miss a cluster using that approach?

Comment: Random Sampling sounds interesting, and it's a likely fallback if I don't have a more scientific approach.

Comment: Seeing as you are using GeoDjango, this would seem to do what you want. https://github.com/biodiv/anycluster/ From a quick glance at the code, it uses k-means clustering or grid based, which seems reasonable. Swap insects for churches, and you are done :D.